# WPF DevExpress DockLayoutManager Layout Issue

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I am using DevExpress' DockLayoutManager in a UserControl.

Within the DockLayoutManager, I use LayoutGroup, and within LayoutGroup, I have two LayoutPanels.  The two LayoutPanels are stacked vartically.  I want the second LayoutPanel to be a fixed height, docked at the bottom left of the UserControl, and I want the first LayoutPanel to have a dynamic height, filling up the remainder of the height of the UserControl, and I want it the be docked in the upper left corner of the UserControl.  I can't seem to get this to work - and - there doesn't seem be any property that specifies where to dock a LayoutPanel (i.e. bottom,top,left etc.).

I am new to these controls, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: Have you tried [DevExpress Support Center](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following xaml:

```
<dxd:LayoutGroup x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <dxd:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" Width="150">
        <dxd:LayoutPanel Caption="First" Height="*"/>
        <dxd:LayoutPanel Caption="Second" Height="100"/>
    </dxd:LayoutGroup>
    <dxd:LayoutGroup Width="*"/>
</dxd:LayoutGroup>
```